# remove corners from RoundedRectangle

Tags: swiftui

I wanted to create View with rounded corners, so I used RoundedRectangle.

```
VStack {
        ForEach(1...10, id: \.self){_ in
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .strokeBorder(Color(UIColor.systemGray2).opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 2)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .background(Color.cell)
                    
                
                VStack {
                    Text("123123")
                    Text("123123")
                    Text("123123")
                    Text("123123")
                    Text("123123")
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    .background(Color.gray)
}
```

[image: Picture]

But corners are not rounded in this case. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I can see the rounded corners. With the ZStack you see also the background of the *table view cell*. You might add a clip shape overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you wanted something like

```
  ZStack(alignment: .top) {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
          .fill(Color.cell)
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
          .strokeBorder(Color(UIColor.systemGray2).opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 2)
      VStack {
          Text("123123")
          Text("123123")
```